# Calling Methods from embedded classes in Java

Tags: java, class, methods

Given Account t, code is meant to enable BankAccount method getBalance to be called for the field savingsAccount within an instance of Account. I've tried various methods of executing this method.
Mainly variations of the follwing:

> Account t = new Account();

t

> t.setSavingsAccount(new BankAccount());

BankAccount@xxxxxx

t.savingsAccount.getBalance();

Static Error: No field in account has name "savingsAccount"

how do i rewrite this code so that savingsAccount is considered a field?
is there a better way to execute the method getBalance from within t?

Relevant Code:

```
    /**
 * A class to track an individuals bank portfolio.
 */
public class Account extends Object{
  private BankAccount savingsAccount = null;              //savings account identification number

 /**
   * A method to set account holder's savings account identification number.
   * @param savings account identification number
   * @return savings account identification number
   */
  public BankAccount setSavingsAccount(BankAccount input){
    savingsAccount = input;
    return savingsAccount;
  }

     /**
      * A method to return account holder's savingsaccount identification number.
      * @return savingsaccount identification number
      */
     public BankAccount getSavingsAccount(){
        return savingsAccount;
     }
    }

/**
 * A class to track the balance and terms of a bank account.
 */
public class BankAccount extends Object{
  private double currentBalance = 0;              //the balance of the account

 /**
  * Returns the balance of the account.
  * @param - void
  * @return the balance of the account
  */
  public double getBalance(){
    return currentBalance;
  }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
System.out.println(t.getSavingsAccount().getBalance());
```

Comment: Side Note:  Setter methods (like 'setSavingsAccount') normally have a 'void' return type.  Unless you're using the Builder pattern.

Answer (score 3):

`savingsAccount` is not a public field. You need to either add an accessor method (i.e. `getSavingsAccount()` or make it public.

Comment: I have a getSavingsAccount method that works, didn't include it in the code for readability. I'll add it to the code above